# Fetch gives empty response while waiting for long period

Tags: node.js, timeout, fetch

I have app made with react and node .

The react app needs to make api call to the node app the node app is running on port 5100 . I am facing problem where I get net_err empty response in the console after waiting long period of time . The thing is my api takes 200s to get the response from the server .

When I hit

```
http://localhost:5100/api/users/wait-ip
```

I get response after 200 second  But when I hit this in the react app

```
fetch('/api/users/wait-ip')
```

I get the following error on console

```
 GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/wait-ip net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

This is my function for api

```
router.get('/api/users/wait-ip',(req,res)=>{
//Others things happen here
 setTimeout(()=>{
    return res.json({
        data:1
    })
},150000)
})
```

This is the response I get while hitting directly on browser after 150seconds

[image: Browser response]
Any help on how to solve this will  be appreciated

Comment: The ports are different in the requests. Maybe changing it from 3000 to 5100 in your GET call.

Comment: No. I am using proxy for thAt

Comment: does it work if you set the `setTimeout` duration to something less like 2 seconds?

Comment: yes . It does if I set less time

Answer (score 2):

Using Node.js API with React is a common use case. I think the reason you are facing the issue in getting response is that you are using `fetch` call synchronously. Always use async/await for it.

```
async function getUsers() {

  let response = await fetch('/api/users/wait-ip');
  let users= await response.json();
  //...
  return users;
}
```

Using the function:

```
getUsers().then(result => {console.log(JSON.stringify(result));});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: it doesn't matter because I am not getting any response in network tab

Comment: @ashokpoudel, I think practically browser taking `200 seconds` to load your React app page is an UX issue. Responsive pages return in less than `3 seconds`. Your Node.js API needs to be optimised to yield data faster. That the API call doesn't return any response in the network tab seems a timeout issue. If you can share a screenshot of response status code and headers etc., it would be great. Having said that,  `async-await` is needed in this case I guess.

Comment: You didn'tu derstood . The app is not taking 200seconds to load . The api call after page load should return data after 150second

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was on both client and the server . 
I have read some of the post on how to fix timeout on the server . One of them was

```
const server = http.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
server.timeout = 200000;
```

Well this worked but only for the direct browser call .

For the  asynchronous call I need to set it for each  function where I wanted it like this

```
 router.get('/wait-ip',(req,res)=>{
 req.timeout =160000;
     setTimeout(()=>{
         return res.json({
             data:1
         })
     },150000)
})
```

And for client part with pxoy it didn't work properly . So what I did was posted the full url

```
fetch('http://localhost:5100/api/users/wait-ip')
```

I hope this helps with other person too

Comment: thanks, its working for me. I have my WEB in PHP and my BACKEND in Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I may be because of the  Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) header.  Usually calling from a browser there is an "OPTION" call that is made followed by, in this case, the "GET".

I would try

```
fetch('/api/users/wait-ip',  {
  mode: 'no-cors' // 'cors' by default
})
```

If this fixes the problem either you force not to use cors on the client side.  Or the server should manage it.  Another option is to allow the proxy to set these headers.

ref: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api

section: Cross-origin requests

Comment: No nothing happens

Comment: In your network tab of the browser is there a call that goes out to your api?  If so, is it the expected type?  If it is, I would suggest looking at the raw.    This would help identify if it is a client, proxy, router, backend or code problem.  Also, I would suggest testing it in an incognito tab because sometimes the calls are cached.

Comment: That was not the case but I fixed it anyway . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This is an API problem. I'd make set breakpoints in your API and make sure the right fields are populated for the response.

[Node.js Debugging Guide...](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/)

Comment: can you give example?

Comment: I'd look up how to setup debugging on your node.js environment (however it is setup), and then debug it. According to having a 200 response there isn't an error, but somewhere in your code you're doing something incorrectly so stepping through your code will provide much needed insight to you and for your post.

Comment: But it gives response if I typed the url directly

Comment: Are you returning anything in the response? If it is null then this is the normal behavior

Comment: No I returned something in response

Comment: The response you're receiving indicates the server returned successfully, and returns null (definition of net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) I'd step through on your console call and figure out why it isn't populating the response.

Comment: I know that too you didn't understood my question . The server returns when url call is made directly but not through the api call